# Octave configure can't find Qscintilla library

Tags: octave, configure, qscintilla

While attempting to build Octave 3.8.2 on a Solaris 10 Sparc 64 machine, configure tells me it can't find the Qscintilla libraries (and several others too), even though I have them.  This is what I'm saying:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin/octave --with-blas=./libblas.so --with-lapack=$HOME/octave-3.8.2/liblapack.a --disable-readline --with-curl-libdir=/opt/csw/lib --with-blas=/opt/csw/lib
```

and this is what I get:

```
configure: WARNING:

I wasn't able to find a suitable style for declaring a push-pull
parser in a bison input file so I'm disabling bison.

configure: WARNING: Qhull library not found -- this will result in loss of functionality of some geometry functions.
configure: WARNING: HDF5 library not found.  Octave will not be able to save or load HDF5 data files.
configure: WARNING: FFTW3 library not found.  The slower FFTPACK library will be used instead.
configure: WARNING: FFTW3F library not found.  The slower FFTPACK library will be used instead.
configure: WARNING: GLPK library not found.  The glpk function for solving linear programs will be disabled.
configure: WARNING: cURL library not found.  The ftp objects, urlread and urlwrite functions will be disabled.
configure: WARNING: FLTK config script not found.  Native graphics will be disabled.
configure: WARNING: qrupdate not found.  The QR & Cholesky updating functions will be slow.
configure: WARNING: AMD library not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: CAMD library not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: COLAMD library not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: CCOLAMD library not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: CHOLMOD library not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: CXSparse library not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: UMFPACK not found.  This will result in some lack of functionality for sparse matrices.
configure: WARNING: ARPACK not found.  The eigs function will be disabled.
configure: WARNING: Qscintilla library not found -- disabling built-in GUI editorconfigure: WARNING:
configure: WARNING: I didn't find the necessary libraries to compile native
configure: WARNING: graphics.  It isn't necessary to have native graphics,
configure: WARNING: but you will need to have gnuplot installed or you won't
configure: WARNING: be able to use any of Octave's plotting commands
configure: WARNING:
configure:
configure: NOTE: Libraries or auxiliary programs may be skipped if they are
configure: NOTE: not found OR if they are missing required features on your
configure: NOTE: system.
```

And this is what I have:

```
# pwd
/opt/csw/lib
# ls *qsci*
libqscintilla2.so     libqscintilla2.so.11.3
libqscintilla2.so.11  libqscintilla2.so.11.3.0
# ls *curl*
libcurl.so.4  libcurl.so.4.3.0
#
```

The question is:

How do I inform the Octave configure of where to find the Qscintilla (and other) libraries it's wanting?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to build octave (the repo version 4.0 or 4.2, I'm not sure) from source, under Ubuntu 64 bits. Like you, there were plenty of lines like

```
configure: WARNING: ... library not found.
```

I had a hard time but I finally managed to make the configure file of octave find the dependencies :

1) I made an alias of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu because I found out that many libraries were installed here instead of in /usr/lib64 where the configure script search them :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64
```

2) I look for octave dependencies with

```
apt-cache depends octave
```

and then I made sure they were installed in synaptics, and most importantly their "-dev" versions.

Then when I made ../configure and it worked for most libraries. Another possible problem you may have is if you don't use the instructions in octave/etc/HACKING, you have to do :

```
cd octave
./bootstrap
mkdir .build
cd .build
../configure
make
```

The only library that is not found on my computer is called 'osmesa' but it seems it's not requested for the 3.8 version so it should not be a problem for you (just saying in case you want to install from the repo source like me).

Answer (score 0):

try building repos
apt-get build-dep octave
or
yum-builddep octave

this worked for me, except blas library for fortran77

then I tried (in Centos -yum style)
yum install lapack64-devel lapack64
and just in case you haven't installed them yet:
yum install gl2ps-devel qrupdate-devel qt-devel qscintilla-devel java-devel

probably there are still many missing but these solved the problems above, at least in part